# If key has value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, $data, that looks like this when printed:

```
[1] => Array 
    [type] => link
[2] => Array
    [type] => photo
[3] => Array
    [type] => video
```

I have a foreach statement for the $data, so each $data holds a [type] key. I need to be able to check if the [type] key has a value of 'link', else a value of 'photo', else a value of 'video'.

Any help would be great. I tried array_key_exists, but that is just to check if a key is present in the data string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $datum) {
   switch ($datum['type']) {
      case 'link':
         //fill in
         break;
      case 'photo':
         //fill in
         break;
      case 'video':
         //fill in
         break;
      default:
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a bit faster on the keyboard than I was ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($data as $v) {

    switch ($v['type']) {
    case 'link':
        echo "it's a link";
        break;
    case 'photo':
        echo "it's a photo";
        break;
    case 'video:
        echo "it's a video";
        break;
    }

}
```